# How to get text data from a single tag without comma seperator using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

below is the html snippet

```
<P class="subtitulo">
 <b>
  <a name="Editores"> Editorial </a>
    "assistant"
 </b>
</p>
```

by using this scrapy code

```
response.css("p.subtitulo *::text").extract()
```

I get

> ['Editorial', ' Assistant']

```
response.css("p.subtitulo *::text").get()
```

I get only "

> Assistant

"
I want the full string without any commas like

> "Editorial Assistant"

Using Beautiful soup I am getting the text without comma. But how to do it with Scrapy. Since I have other roles separated by commas I don't want to use split().

This is the page url
http://www.scielo.org.co/revistas/zop/iedboard.htm

Comment: Try `getall()`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid split? If a method is supposed to return data in a particular format, you'll have to deal with the response in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by invoking  `.join()` and  `.getall()` method as follows:

```
import scrapy
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['http://www.scielo.org.co/revistas/zop/iedboard.htm']
        
    def parse(self, response):
        for p in response.css('.subtitulo')[1:]:
            yield {
            'Name': ''.join(p.css("::text").getall())
            }
```

**Output:**

```
{'Name': 'Editorial Assistant'}
2022-08-08 15:39:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.scielo.org.co/revistas/zop/iedboard.htm>
{'Name': 'Editorial Committee '}
2022-08-08 15:39:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.scielo.org.co/revistas/zop/iedboard.htm>
{'Name': 'Scientific Committee'}
2022-08-08 15:39:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.scielo.org.co/revistas/zop/iedboard.htm>
{'Name': 'Editorial Universidad Del Norte'}
```